# Mongo / Rails Mongoid index on embedded field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm getting something incredibly simple wrong, and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Fairly new to Mongo

Using Rails 3.2.6 with MongoDB and Mongoid. Trying to add an index to an embedded field.

I have a model 'Scheme', which has embedded 'Referals'. "Referal" has a field 'to_code' (string). I want to index this field.

```
class Scheme
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embeds_many :referals
  index "referals.to_code" => 1

class Referal
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embedded_in :scheme
```

when I run 'rake db:mongoid:create_indexes' this fails with this error:

```
 Not a Mongoid parent model: app/models/referal.rb
 rake aborted!
 Invalid index specification {"referals.to_code"=>1}; should be either a string, symbol, or an array of arrays.
```

As far as I can tell this follows the Mongoid documentation exactly, so not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using mongoid 3 syntax with version 2 of the gem.

The error message indicates that the mongoid 2 index syntax is expected: http://two.mongoid.org/docs/indexing.html

You are trying to use the mongoid 3 index syntax: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html

Check what version of the gem you are using and adjust your syntax accordingly.